# Access Data From a "Before" Event Subscriber in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony

My project is uses a "Before" Event Subscriber to lookup information before the Controller is executed.  I'm following the pattern described in the [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html).  However my Subscriber retrieves some information from the database, and I want to be able to access that object in the Controller.  I can store it as a request attribute:

```
$request->attributes->set('object', $object);
```

But this doesn't seem efficient.  What's the preferred way to access Event Subscriber "Before" data in a Controller?

Comment: It needs to be done in request.

Comment: Technically you could use the session or maybe even a service to stash the data but basically your subscriber is adding additional request oriented information.  So it makes good sense to use the request.  I don't understand why you would think this is not "efficient".  Request attributes are really just an array class.

Comment: I read somewhere that a doctrine object shouldn't be sent this way.  i'll test and maybe strip the object down to an array

Comment: No problem with sending Doctrine objects.  Where you get in trouble with doctrine is when you try to persist objects between requests outside of the database.